# How to Customize Filter in Kendo AutoComplete MVC Control?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

Here is my code, I need to filter my data text in autocomplete in the way, first it should fitler with startwith operator by default once the user typed text is not available from the list it should change the operator to contains to return a result.

```
@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
      .Name("AnnotationAutoComplete")
      .DataTextField("ConcatNote")
      .HighlightFirst(true).Filter("startswith")

          .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["AnnotationList"])
          .Events(ev => ev.Close("onAnnotationAutoCompleteClose")))
```

Comment: `@(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete().Name("AnnotationAutoComplete").DataTextField("ConcatNote").HighlightFirst(true).Filter("contains")` => is this what you want, or changing filter operator when user typing more letters? Currently the context still unclear, provide more details for objectives you want to achieve.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, thanks for a quick reply,  I need to change the filter operator when user typing more letters

Comment: Got a work around from telerik support - http://dojo.telerik.com/opAvu/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This customization is kendo autocomplete can be done using the set option based on child list length, got the Solution from telerik Support team, I have created a demo for this please refer below link,

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/filter-customization-in-kendo-autocomplete